# What is more efficient when using a for loop?

Tags: arrays, performance, for-loop, variables, pseudocode

In a lot of for loops that work with arrays I see `i < arr.length()` as the 2nd statement
Would this:
`for(i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){`
    `//do something`
`}`
be LESS efficient than this:
`size = arr.length();`
`for(i = 0; i < size; i++){`
    `//do something`
`}`?
Or is the difference so small I shouldn't care?
This question only applies to languages that need to use a function in order to find the length of an array/list, unlike java, for example, which is object-oriented and arrays have a length propriety `arr.length`

Comment: Do you want to compute the length again and again, or do you want the run loop for same length ? Having i < arr.length() as condition in for loop will always try to get length of array for every iteration which might be in-efficient depending upon the compiler.

Comment: I'm talking about when the length is constant, I almost always see `i < arr.getSize()` as the second statement in tutorials for beginners and I wondered if it's bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version can be slower regarding the language, the compiler, its configuration and the loop condition.

Indeed, in C, C++ and Java for example the function is called at each iteration and thus the resulting program can be *slower when optimizations are disabled*. Other languages, such as Python, have a different kind of loops which walk through given iterables / ranges (eg. list, generators) and the value is evaluated once.
In your case, no performance differences should be seen if optimizations are enabled since the function call `arr.length()` is usually a constant (in the context of the loop execution) and **most compilers are good enough to detect this and to produce a fast equivalent code** (you can see a simple example in C++ [here](https://godbolt.org/z/TdhPGP)). However, please note that interpreters generally do *not* perform such optimizations.